# Wordpress Turn off new user email with username and password to both admin AND USER

Tags: wordpress, email

I am using the new wordpress v 4.7 and I would like to disable the email notification that goes out to the user showing them their username and password but I cannot seem to turn it off.I do not want to send both of these together(username and password) as it a security risk. How do I stop this email from going out or at least heavily edit it? Thanks